# Как в один скрипт поместить несколько id форм?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, господа!

Язык JS мне не знаком, но столкнулась с такой задачей. Есть скрипт который срабатывает после ввода данных в input формы отправки сообщения. Как мне в этом скрипте описать id разных форм, т.к. разные формы должны вести на разные страницы с благодарностями.

Вот сам скрипт:

```
// ClearForm
function clearForm(form) {
    $(':input', form).each(function () {
        var type = this.type;
        var tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea') $(this).val('');
        else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio') this.checked = false;
        else if (tag == 'select') this.selectedIndex = -1;
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function () {
        var form_id = $(this);
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendmail.php",
            data: str,
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg == 'OK') {
                    document.location.href = "http://delmit.eurodir.ru/lee/thx1.html";
                } else if (msg == 'FAILED') {
                    clearForm(form_id);
                    form_id.children('.form_fit').html("<div class='ansver-wrap'><div class='succsessfuly'>Ошибка <br /> <a href='#'>Пробовать ещё раз</a></div></div>");
                } else {
                    result = msg;
                    alert(result);
                    // $('#result_form').append(result);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Возвращай с сервера в переменную msg не OK или FAILED, а адрес страницы с благодарностью или FALSE.
Тогда javascript при получении положительного результата будет примерно таким

```
success: function(msg){
  if (msg!='FALSE') {
      document.location.href = msg;
  } else {
      clearForm(form_id);
      alert('При отправке формы произошла ошибка');
  }
}
```

Еще можно в msg писать массив, где первый элемент - OK или FAILED, а второй, например, сообщение или адрес страницы для перехода.

**Обновление**
Если ты просто хочешь указать id разных форм, то в переменную `form_id` записывай не `$(this)`, а нужную форму, типа `$('#form2_id');`